# Email validation using regular expression in PHP

Tags: php, regex, email

I am pretty much new with regular expression. I am developing a project in PHP and  i need to validate email address. After searching in this site and google i found the following regular expression says it should work best.

```
if (preg_match("/^(?!(?:(?:\x22?\x5C[\x00-\x7E]\x22?)|(?:\x22?[^\x5C\x22]\x22?)){255,})(?!(?:(?:\x22?\x5C[\x00-\x7E]\x22?)|(?:\x22?[^\x5C\x22]\x22?)){65,}@)(?:(?:[\x21\x23-\x27\x2A\x2B\x2D\x2F-\x39\x3D\x3F\x5E-\x7E]+)|(?:\x22(?:[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x21\x23-\x5B\x5D-\x7F]|(?:\x5C[\x00-\x7F]))*\x22))(?:\.(?:(?:[\x21\x23-\x27\x2A\x2B\x2D\x2F-\x39\x3D\x3F\x5E-\x7E]+)|(?:\x22(?:[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x21\x23-\x5B\x5D-\x7F]|(?:\x5C[\x00-\x7F]))*\x22)))*@(?:(?:(?!.*[^.]{64,})(?:(?:(?:xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*\.){1,126}){1,}(?:(?:[a-z][a-z0-9]*)|(?:(?:xn--)[a-z0-9]+))(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*)|(?:\[(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9][:\]]){7,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?)))|(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){5}:)|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){5,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3}:)?)))?(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))(?:\.(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))){3}))\]))$/iD", strtolower($mail_address))) {
    echo "valid email";
}
```

But when I use it I get error says,

```
"Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found"
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: E-mail validation is a murky trench, but I have to say your regex looks rather suspicious; here's a thread with a good answer, which references the regex used in Django: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217682/checking-validity-of-email-in-django-python
Edit: Wayne's answer below should work well for you, too!

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Use this instead of a regular expression:

```
if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
     //Valid email!
}
```

Using regular expressions to validate email addresses is [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/491494) as it is certainly [not pretty](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html), especially if you don't want to exclude somebody who has a valid email address that is correct according to RFC 822 grammar.

http://www.php.net/filter_var is your best bet.

A crazy example of a regex that attempts to validate email addresses according to RFC 822 grammar:

```
(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:(?:(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
)+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:
\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(
?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ 
\t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\0
31]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\
](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+
(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:
(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*|(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z
|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)
?[ \t])*)*\<(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:@(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\
r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[
 \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)
?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
)*))*(?:,@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[
 \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*
)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
)+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*)
*:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)?(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+
|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r
\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:
\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t
]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031
]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](
?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?
:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?
:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*\>(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)|(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?
:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?
[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)*:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:(?:(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] 
\000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|
\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>
@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"
(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
)*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\
".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?
:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[
\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*|(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-
\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(
?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)*\<(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:@(?:[^()<>@,;
:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([
^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\"
.\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\
]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*(?:,@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\
[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\
r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] 
\000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]
|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*)*:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)?(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \0
00-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\
.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,
;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?
:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*
(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".
\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[
^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]
]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*\>(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:,\s*(
?:(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\
".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(
?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[
\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t
])*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t
])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?
:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|
\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*|(?:
[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\
]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)*\<(?:(?:\r\n)
?[ \t])*(?:@(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["
()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)
?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>
@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*(?:,@(?:(?:\r\n)?[
 \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,
;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]
)*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\
".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*)*:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)?
(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".
\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\.(?:(?:
\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z|(?=[\[
"()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|"(?:[^\"\r\\]|\\.|(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t]))*"(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])
*))*@(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])
+|\Z|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*)(?:\
.(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\".\[\] \000-\031]+(?:(?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])+|\Z
|(?=[\["()<>@,;:\\".\[\]]))|\[([^\[\]\r\\]|\\.)*\](?:(?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*\>(?:(
?:\r\n)?[ \t])*))*)?;\s*)
```

Comment: I like `filter_var()` but isn't `user@localhost` (yes, I'm aware of RFC 2822 vs RFC 2821 debate, just for validation 2821 is out of question because we are not yet talking about sending email). And what about **IDNA** acc. RFC 3490 `ex: user@dömain.com`. Agreed that for general purpose, this one works just fine, but still is not 100% reliable.

Comment: Ohh! and by the way, worth mentioning that [RFC 822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt) is obsolete, [RFC 2822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt) is now in for Internet Message Format

Comment: `filter_var` is not entirely reliable, because I've had cases where a perfectly valid email - `petrović@fictionaldomain.com` was rejected. Am still looking for a way to include this - `/^\p{L}+$/ui` - into filter_var, since it seems to cover what I need - validating emails, and allowing non-English latin characters through.

Comment: GOD VERSION OF REGEX FOR EMAIL VALIDATION :)

Answer (score 11):

it looks like you don't really need that bigger code to just validate a email.

```
<?php
$email = "abc123@sdsd.com"; 
$regex = '/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/'; 
if (preg_match($regex, $email)) {
 echo $email . " is a valid email. We can accept it.";
} else { 
 echo $email . " is an invalid email. Please try again.";
}           
?>
```

Try this one and let me know

Comment: Does not work (for example) for domain extensions with more than 3 chars. Don't use this.

Answer (score 10):

You should use the function `filter_vars()` to validate your input instead of your own regexp.

Example:

```
filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```

More info in the documentation : http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Comment: I like `filter_var()` but isn't `user@localhost` (yes, I'm aware of RFC 2822 vs RFC 2821 debate, just for validation 2821 is out of question because we are not yet talking about sending email). And what about **IDNA** acc. RFC 3490 `ex: user@dömain.com`. Agreed that for general purpose, this one works just fine, but still is not 100% reliable.

Answer (score 7):

try this regx it would work fine

```
/^([a-z0-9_\.-]+)@([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})$/
```

or php filter [`filter_var`](https://www.php.net/filter_var)

```
 filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```

like

```
if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
     //yup its valid email
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `iD` at the end of the regex

Answer (score 2):

Weird I just tried your code that works well with me ?!
Try closing any chain with the character '....' instead of "...."

Answer (score 1):

I got here looking for a solution and the answer presented by Wayne Whitty do the job, indeed.

BTW, I think it is good to mention that `filter_var` function is not RFC5321 compliant. Altought the docs does not say it is, some RFC5321 valid email address will be flagged as invalid by this function, like:

- localpart.ending.with.dot.@example.com
- (comment)localpart@example.com
- "this is v@lid!"@example.com
- "much.more unusual"@example.com
- postbox@com
- admin@mailserver1
- "()<>[]:,;@\"\!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{}| ~.a"@example.org
- " "@example.org

As presented by this comment http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-var.php#112492

Answer (score 0):

Use these regular expressions to perform a more thorough validation. For example it prevents adjacent periods in email address like aaa..bbb@example..com which is invalid according to RFC 822.

```
function isValidEmail($email)
{
    return preg_match('/\A[a-z0-9]+([-._][a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,4}\z/', $email)
        && preg_match('/^(?=.{1,64}@.{4,64}$)(?=.{6,100}$).*/', $email);
}
```

See [validate email address using regular expression in PHP](http://seaf-email.blogspot.com/p/code.html#php).

Comment: Doesn't work for many valid emails like: `Jean-François+@anydomain.museum`

Answer (score 0):

There more than one ways to check if an e-mail is valid.

One simple way is to use this function:

```
function validate($email) {
    return preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/", $email);    
}
```

It is from a code snippet found here: [Basic Email Validation in PHP](http://www.codeslices.net/snippets/basic-email-validation-in-php)

Although this implementation would work most of the time it may allow some wrong emails.
The following implementation ahould be 100% accurate but is also quite complex:

```
function validate($email) {

    $isValid = true;
    $atIndex = strrpos($email, "@");

    if (is_bool($atIndex) && !$atIndex) {
        $isValid = false;
    } else {
        $domain = substr($email, $atIndex + 1);
        $local = substr($email, 0, $atIndex);
        $localLen = strlen($local);
        $domainLen = strlen($domain);

        if ($localLen < 1 || $localLen > 64) {
            $isValid = false;
        } else if ($domainLen < 1 || $domainLen > 255) {
            $isValid = false;
        } else if ($local[0] == '.' || $local[$localLen - 1] == '.') {
            $isValid = false;
        } else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $local)) {
            $isValid = false;
        } else if (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.]+$/', $domain)) {
            $isValid = false;
        } else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $domain)) {
            $isValid = false;
        } else if (!preg_match('/^(\\\\.|[A-Za-z0-9!#%&`_=\\/$\'*+?^{}|~.-])+$/', str_replace("\\\\", "", $local))) {
            if (!preg_match('/^"(\\\\"|[^"])+"$/', str_replace("\\\\", "", $local))) {
                $isValid = false;
            }
        }

        if ($isValid && !(checkdnsrr($domain, "MX") || checkdnsrr($domain ,"A"))) {
            $isValid = false;
        }
    }

    return $isValid;
}
```

This code is from snippet found here: [Strict Email Validation in PHP](http://www.codeslices.net/snippets/strict-email-validation-in-php)

Hope this helps!

Comment: The second implementation is not valid. For example, `foo@héhé.fr` is a valid email address and the function rejects it. Same thing for `foo(bar)@yahoo.com`, `foo" "@yahoo.com`, `foo"<"@yahoo.com`, `foo">"@yahoo.com`, etc.

Comment: simple but what if an email domain ends with ".co.uk" ? this pattern will not work then... plus, you can replace this "a-zA-Z0-9_" with \w

Answer (score 0):

```
/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix
```

Answer (score -1):

Email validation regex (domain with sub domains)

```
^((([a-z0-9]+[\-]{0,1})+[a-z0-9]+?\.)+[a-z0-9][a-z0-9|\-]+[a-z0-9])@([a-z0-9]+[\-|\.]{0,1}[a-z0-9]+)+(.[a-z0-9]{2,})+$
```

Sample tests https://regex101.com/r/w5VBdf/20

Domain with sub domains

```
^([a-z0-9]+[\.|\-]{0,1}[a-z0-9](.[a-z0-9]{2,})+)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/4Un8Tz/2

Email username

```
^([a-z0-9]+[\.|\-]{0,1}[a-z0-9]{1,})+@$
```

https://regex101.com/r/4Un8Tz/6

Comment: This solution may not answer the OP question

Comment: Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Comment: You can replace `{0,1}` with `?`, `{1,}` with `+` and `[\.|\-]` with `[.-]`, you should learn some basics regex (and reread the question), have a look at https://www.regular-expressions.info/