# Regex for specific domain name

Tags: php, regex

I am a regex noob but I wish to write a regex to check for email for domain name xyz.com.it if user key in abc.com or other TLD domain names, it will pass. If user keys in xyz after the @ then, only xyz.com.it will pass, others like xyz.net.it or xyz.net will not pass.Any idea how to do it?

I had tried

```
var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/; 
var regexEmail = regex.test($('#email').val());
```

that only validates normal email

Comment: What you have tried so far? Post your attempts? Post some possible inputs and expected outputs

Comment: I had tried var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
var regexEmail = regex.test($('#email').val());

Comment: @Uchiha , it only validates normail email

Comment: ok sure thing @uchiha

Comment: Your question is tagged [php], but your code is JS. Which one is it?

Comment: it JS inside PHP, sorry didn't elaborate well

Comment: So the accepted answer doesn't really answer it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now instead of using `regex` you can simply use [`strstr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) function of PHP like as

```
$email = "xyz@xyz.com";
$email2 = "xyz@xyz.net";
$valid_domain = "@xyz.com";

function checkValidDomain($email, $valid_domain){
    if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false){
        if(strstr($email,"@") == $valid_domain){
            return "Valid";
        }else{
            return "Invalid";
        }
    }else{
        return "Invalid Email";
    }
}

echo checkValidDomain($email, $valid_domain);// Valid
echo checkValidDomain($email2, $valid_domain);// Invalid
```

Why I didn't used regex over here you can read many of those threads on SO too [Email validation using regular expression in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719821/email-validation-using-regular-expression-in-php) and [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: @uchida thanks,I am using JQuery though. Your solution is logical but it only deals with part of my problem. I'm looking for validating normal emails too... but thanks anyway

Comment: This doesn't take into account valid emailaddresses like `"foo@bar"@example.com`

Comment: The pattern you have chosen is the broken javascript one. My initial comment also still stands.

Comment: This will still fail. The point is you cannot simply do a `strstr` because it finds the first occurrence of a character. https://3v4l.org/Kijfh Also `if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false){` will flag valid emails is incorrect.

Comment: So what can be the case over here @PeeHaa