# Django REST Framework: email+password token-based authentication for one to one custom user

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, http-token-authentication

I need help with token-based authentication for a custom user model.

I have a User model that inherits from `AbstractBaseUser`:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

I have a `DojoMaster` model that extends the `User` model and am using a `post_save` receiver:

**`models.py`**

```
class DojoMaster(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    phone = models.BigIntegerField()
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

I have added the following authentication classes:

**`settings.py`**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'Default_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    )
}
```

To access token authentication I have:

**`urls.py`**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^get-token', obtain_auth_token)
]
```

I have the following `DojoMaster` user:

```
{
    "user": {
        "name": "XYZ",
        "email": "xyz@mail.com",
        "password": "p@55w0rd"
    },
    "username": "iAmXYZ",
    "phone": 2685211,
    "country": 575
}
```

When I try to get the authentication token with `{"email": "xyz@mail.com", "password": "p@55w0rd"}` I get a Status 400 error `{"username": ["This field is required."]}`

When I use `{"username": "xyz@mail.com", "password": "p@55w0rd"}` I get a Status 400 error `{"non_field_errors": ["Unable to log in with provided credentials."]}`

I tried using advice from posts such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058326/django-rest-framework-obtain-auth-token-using-email-instead-username) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698456/django-rest-auth-email-instead-of-username).

How can I use `email`+`password` to perform token-based authentication for such a custom user?

Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just inherit from **AbstractUser** instead of **AbstractBaseUser** since you are not doing much overriding. And just declare

```
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']
USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
```

Hope this works for you