# To check Email is valid format or not in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to check whether the email is valid format in django. I have used syntax `re.match("[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+", email)` for checking email is valid format. The syntax is correct but it's only for checking addresses like `xxx.yyy@gmail.com`. But I need to check addresses like **`xxx.yyy@yahoo.co.in`**. How can I do that in validation? Please help me to do that. I need to check those two things in a single regex.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217682/checking-validity-of-email-in-django-python)

Comment: What do the asterisks indicate? Just use `search` instead of `match` then.

Answer (score 4):

Django has its own email validator you can use ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/validators/#validate-email))

```
from django.core.validators import validate_email

try:
    validate_email("xxx.yyy@yahoo.co.in")
except:
    # not valid email
```

Comment: no it's not working when i pass the value "xxx.yyy@yahoo.coin"     it's a wrong value which i passed

Comment: mhh what version of django are you using? i tested this with 1.4 and 1.8 and it works for me

Comment: ok, wait is `xxx.yyy@yahoo.co.in` valid for you or not?? because for django this would be a valid email address.